# Convert pandas timeseries to xts format using rpy2

Tags: python, r, pandas, xts, rpy2

I am trying to call the function 'Nelson.Siegel' in the'YieldCurve' Package using rpy2. 'Nelson.Siegel' takes an xts file (rates) and a list (Marurity) as inputs, it seems that I have to convert pandas data frame into xts format, and I am not sure how to achieve it. And I am not sure if I call the Nelson.Siegel function in the correct way. Any help will be appreicated.

I try to use pandas2ri.activate() to change data type from pandas to r but it seems that I need to further make it into xts format. I try to import as.xts in xts package but it doesn't work together with rpy2.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
base = importr('base')
utils = importr('utils')
utils.install_packages('YieldCurve', repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")
Yieldcurve= importr('YieldCurve')
NelsonSiegel = robjects.r('Nelson.Siegel')
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
Maturity=[0.5,1,2]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,30,size=(10,3)),
                   columns=["1","2","3"],
                  index=pd.date_range("20190101", periods=10))
NSParam= NelsonSiegel(df, Maturity)
```

Error message: Error in is.finite(if (is.character(from)) from <- as.numeric(from) else from) : 
  default method not implemented for type 'list'

Answer (score 0):

Specifying that `Maturity` should be an vector rather than let the converter assume that a list is wanted might solve this:

```
Maturity=robjects.vectors.IntVector([0.5,1,2])
```

Otherwise, first check whether your pandas data frame is safely converter to an R data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,30,size=(10,3)),
                  columns=["1","2","3"],
                  index=pd.date_range("20190101", periods=10))
base.print(df)
```